# How to calculate the cumulative baseline hazard function for a CoxPH model

Tags: r, survival, cox-model, hazard, proportional-hazards

I have read that the following formula is used to estimate the cumulative baseline hazard function:

[image: Cumulative Baseline Hazard Approximation]

I also know that the basehaz command in R will also calculate an estimate for the cumulative baseline hazard.

When i build a 1 variable coxPH model in R using the BRESLOW method for ties, the output from the basehaz command matches up with my manual calculations made using the formula given above

However, when i build the same coxPH model using the EFRON method for ties, my manual calculations **do not** match up with the basehaz output from this coxPH model (see findings below)

[image: Manual Calculations vs Basehaz]

My question is, how is the basehaz calculated when EFRON ties are used as it simply cannot be done using the formula given in the first picture.

Comment: Your $t$ is $2,3,4,5,6,7,8$ it seems there are no ties at all.

Comment: I have summarized the data in the tables. For example,  at time t=2 there were 373 deaths, at time t=3 there were 431 deaths and so on. I can provide a more detailed spreadsheet that shows exactly how each of these things were calculated if you would like?